# AJAX with protoypjs, multiple targets?

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, target

I am using the following prototypjs to make an AJAX object:

```
function SendData(){
 var url = 'formvalidate.php';
 var pars = 'username='+escape($F('username'))+'&email='+$F('email');
 var target = 'message';
 var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(target, url, {method: 'get', parameters: pars});
}
```

"message" is outputing to

Thats fine if I want to have text displayed always in the same place.

But in *addition* to text being displayed, I also want to, for example, change the background color of my input fields based on certain events.

So it is possible to have more than one "var target" in one protyopejs AJAX object? (Instead of creating yet another instance?)

Or what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax.Request` instead.

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    $('target1') = transport.responseText;
    $('target2') = transport.responseText;
  }
})
```

http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request

Comment: Thanks very much for this, but how do I pass data to these variables from my php file? I mean how to do i assign a variable to target2 from the php file?

Comment: @PartisanEntity the PHP code could JSON encode the different parts in an object and return that. The Javascript code could then retrieve it with [`responseJSON`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Response/prototype/responseJSON/) and separate the necessary parts.